# Spark Thriftserver: Stream jar was not found exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying run a Hive UDTF in thriftserver.

The UDTF is registered, but doesn't run and fails with a function not found exception.

Now, what is strange is that after this failed attempt of running the UDTF, nothing runs on thriftserver, even the basic SELECT queries. Every query fails with the following exception:

```
Error: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 36.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 36.0 (TID 73, hdp8004d02.fuzzyl.com): java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream '/jars/experiments-1.0.jar' was not found.
```

Here, experiments-1.0.jar is the jar file I used to run the Hive UDTF.

It's only when I restart the thriftserver, the queries run.

I am running it on HDP 2.5 with spark 2.0.0

The complete stack trace of the error is:

```
17/02/23 13:51:17 ERROR SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Error running hive query:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 36.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 36.0 (TID 73, hdp8004d02.fuzzyl.com): java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream '/jars/experiments-1.0.jar' was not found.
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:222)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:121)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:85)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please put screen from you resource manager or logs regarding  running state of containers for thrift service.

Comment: Thrift server is launched as a yarn application and is in running state.

Comment: How you launch your application ? command

Comment: The thriftserver I am running is installed as a service in HDP 2.5. And I am executing the SQL queries by connecting to the thiftserver using beeline.

`beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10016 -d org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`